# Keyboard input on any Java 6 application on OSX Leopard

Tags: java, macos

I get no keyboard feedback on any java application I run with Java 6 (64-bit) on OSX Leopard 10.5.7.

It happens with any swing application, or even with eclipse 3.5 64-bit (which is a SWT-cocoa application).

Did't find any reference to this problem on the web...

Comment: Do you talk about a program you've written by yourself? If not, this isn't really a programming question and does no belong here...

Comment: At first my application didn't get response. Then I realized it happened with any application.

It's a kind of problem developers have to face, because it's a deployment issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my keyboard layout. I was using a custom "US International" layout. Now I installed the layout from http://www.brockerhoff.net/usi/ and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Does the window/control have the input focus?